# Checking if user input is a letter

Tags: c#

I'm receiving some user input through a `TextBox` which is then being converted to an int so it can be used in further calculations when I click the `Calculate` button.

I have checked to see if the `TextBox` is empty when the `Calculate` button is clicked, if it is, then a message box appears. Now I realised I need to check to make sure it is a number being input, not a letter. I'm looking for something similar to this

```
if(hoursInput.Text == "" || hoursInput.Text contains "a-z")
{
    \\ handle error
}
else
{
    \\ continue with code
}
```

EDIT:

The user input is converted to an int in the `else` block, but I do not want the function to reach this stage of converting from string to int if the user input contains letters, which is why I want to check to see if the user input contains any letters in the `if` block

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, use `Int32.TryParse` which will return a `bool` of whether or not the input could be parsed to an `Int32`. One of the parameters is an `out` and will become the `Int32` if the input could be parsed.

See:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx

```
if(hoursInput.Text == "" || !Int32.TryParse(hoursInput.Text, out number))
{
\\ handle error
}
else
{
\\ continue with code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to check anything explicitly:

```
int aNumber;
if (!Int32.TryParse(hoursInput.Text, out aNumber)) {
    // handle error
} else {
    // handle `aNumber`
}
```